Distribution independent detection of screen lock event
I am writing an application which needs to pause whenever the screen is locked.
Since the users of the application will be running different DM's (Gnome, Mate, Cinnamon, XFCE, Plasma etc.) I am looking for a DM independent way of detecting the screen lock event.
Most of the solutions on SE (e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229618/detect-that-the-system-is-locked#1229619) depend on polling the gnome-screensaver which will not work with other DM's
Is a clean DM independent solution for detecting screen lock available? or do I have to check for and poll every locker application for every DM?
PS: If possible I would also want my script to await <screenlock event> instead of frequently polling for file/program.

If there were a DM-independent API, I'd expect xdg-screensaver to use it, and in the source code there are mentions of the org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver DBus service, which seems cross-DE. But even with that, the script has fallback code for a bunch of DEs.

So I'd expect that even if you use org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver (supported by GNOME and KDE according to the script's source code), you'd need to add custom code for other DEs.
